# Git pull changes for active branch

Tags: git, github

Question is simple how can I pull changes for my active branch without using full command `git pull origin <branch_name>` there must be shortcut for this command, is there?

```
git checkout -b feature_x
git push origin feature_x
git pull origin feature_x  # is there shortcut, keeping in mind this is active branch
```

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Based on bellow accepted answer this is output which explains more

```
>git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@github.com:XXX/FooBar.git
  Push  URL: git@github.com:XXX/FooBar.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    master       tracked
    feature_x    tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    master       merges with remote master
    feature_x    merges with remote feature_x    
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    master       pushes to master       (up to date)
    feature_x    pushes to feature_x    (up to date)
```

Comment: Doesn't it work just doing `git pull`?

Comment: Ad says something in lines of "You asked me to pull without telling me which branch you want to merge with, ... please specify which branch you want to use on the command line and try again"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git push --set-upstream origin feature_x` will allow just `git pull` to be a shorthand for `git pull origin feature_x`

Comment: When I delete branch, does it switch back to master?

Comment: You can't delete the branch you're on, so no.

Comment: @Dolphin First of all, you must currently on that branch feature_x.

Comment: OK I have played a little and what this does is sets `feature_x` branch to work with `feature_x remote branch` so this covers `push/pull`. When you switch to `master branch` it will automatically work with `remote master branch`. Sweet, Thank you.